# Adobe CQ/AEM - Groovy to Activate a page

Tags: aem

I’m very new to Groovy. Using Groovy I am trying to determine a page’s activation status and also activate/deactivate a page.  This is the core elements of my code and it’s throwing an exception.

```
import com.day.cq.replication.Replicator;
import javax.jcr.Session;

Session session = slingRequest.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);

path='/content/geometrixx/en/';

def getStats = getReplicationStatus(session, path);
def rp = replicate(session, "ACTIVATE", path);
```

Here's the exception it throws:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.getReplicationStatus() is applicable for argument types: ($Proxy10, java.lang.String) values: [session-admin-977089, /content/geometrixx/en/]
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:9)
```

I tried a few things but they don't seem to be working.  replicate returns void but that didn't seem to change anything.  Declaring if of Replicator doesn't seem to work.   It's almost like it can't find the import.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know anything about groovy. However seeing your code, you are not calling getReplicationStatus method on the replicator object and hence it is trying to find it within your class / file itself. You can get the replicator through sling.getService() on top of which you can invokde the getReplicationStatus method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.day.cq.replication.Replicator;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationActionType;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationStatus;
import javax.jcr.Session;  
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

def replicator = sling.getService(Replicator.class);
def replicationstatus = sling.getService(ReplicationStatus.class);
def path = '/content/geometrixx/en/';

// Find current Replication Status
rs = replicator.getReplicationStatus(session, path);

GregorianCalendar date = rs.getLastPublished();

println("Published on: " + date.getTime());
println("Last Published By: " + rs.getLastPublishedBy());
println("Path is activated: " + rs.isActivated());
println("Path is delivered: " +rs.isDelivered());


// Activate the Page
def rp = replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, path);

// Verify new Replication Status
rs = replicator.getReplicationStatus(session, path);

date = rs.getLastPublished();

println("Published on: " + date.getTime());
println("Last Published By: " + rs.getLastPublishedBy());
println("Path is activated: " + rs.isActivated());
println("Path is deactivated: " + rs.isDeactivated());
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy Console provides some extension methods. 
One of them are:

**activate(String path)** - Activate the node at the given path.

**activate(String path, ReplicationOptions options)** - Activate the node at the  given path with supplied options.

**deactivate(String path)** - Deactivate the node at the given path.

**deactivate(String path, ReplicationOptions options)** - Deactivate the node at the given path with supplied options.

So your script should look like the following one:

```
activate('/content/geometrixx/en/')
```

Full list of the methods is available in Methods tab on Groovy Console page (/etc/groovyconsole.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in the code you provided:

1. Methods **getReplicationStatus()** and **replicate()** are not defined in the scope. 
   To use **replicate()** you need to get com.day.cq.replication.Replicator object.

```java
 def replicator = sling.getService(Replicator.class)
```

2. com.day.cq.replication.Replicator.replicate() method has different signature comparing with which you are using. 

   There is need to provide **ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE** object instead of "ACTIVATE" String.

```java
public abstract void replicate(Session paramSession, ReplicationActionType paramReplicationActionType, String paramString)
```

3. "session" variable already defined in the scope, no need to get it from ResourceResolver.

Final code sample:

```java
import com.day.cq.replication.Replicator;
import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationActionType
import javax.jcr.Session;

def replicator = sling.getService(Replicator.class)
def path = '/content/geometrixx/en/';
def rp = replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, path);
```